# `\require{mhchem}` not working in jupyter markdown cell

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, mathjax

I typed in a markdown cell in a juypter notebook and inside juypter lab: `$$\require{mhchem} \pu{123 kJ//mol}$$`. That is not rendered as wanted. Any hint?

Comment: Have you tried using kathjax instead? See https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/9757#issuecomment-775494789

Comment: Thanks, i treid both commands and get a `Building jupyterlab assets (build:prod:minimize)`

Comment: That would be expected.

Comment: ok but then how is the right way to do it, if not via `! jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/katex-extension` in jupyterlab, nor with the `require`?

Comment: I do not understand. The "building jupyterlab assets" is a normal message during installation of extensions in JupyterLab. What is your question?

Comment: after that i am not able to use the packages that i have tried to install, so i don't know why all these extensions are not working after the installation.